# How to discount for a particular simple product under a bundle product?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I have bundle products.
I want to apply discount to only those bundle product in my cart which contains specific simple product (meaning to reflect in grandtotal) else no discounts

Consider bundle product as **B** and its simple product as **S1, S2, S3 with prices 40, 60, 80 respectively**
For ex. If any bundle product have **S2**,then give 50% discount for the amount for that simple product.
Assume my cart got 2 bundle product **B1 & B2** in which **B1** contains **S1,S2,S3** whereas **B2** contains **S1,S3**,

so that cart total after applying discount coupon should be like this:
**B1: 150** & **B2: 120** thereby totalling 270
**B1 (S1:40, S2:30, S3:80) and B2 (S1:40, S3:80)
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only possible with a fixed price discount using a coupon which applies to all bundles which have that simple product. But you would need to manage the list of bundles in the cart rule and the fixed price discount in case your simple product price changes.

Comment: Do you have idea via codes?